# How to create a line chart showing change over time in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, data-visualization

I have snapshots of datasets and I want to create a line chart showing the change.
For instance, each snapshot looks something like this (with different values):

[image]

I wish to create a line chart showing the change in amount for Q1 and Q2, i.e., a line for Q1 showing the change in amount over time (using the snapshots taken), similar line for Q2 and a line for total (total amount) in the same chart Also, I want to add a slicer for the product.

Comment: You forgot something! ;-)

Comment: All your values are unique; if you want to show different lines for the quarters, but also have a product slicer, how will you then create a line? Each observation will be effectively only one point?